# Stored procedure inserting the same value over and over again

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm facing an unlikely event handled by the Stored Procedure for MySQL.
I've managed to search for multiple rows in the stored procedure but I am testing it before I can go live.

My current issue is that the result from the below query returns 100 different result set.

But when the query to insert is where the problem begins. It's inserting the same `@UID` over and over again until it reaches 100.

Is there a way I can increment to the next row before I even insert it?

```
DECLARE pSpot INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE con INT(11) DEFAULT 97;
DECLARE tempString VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE x  INT(11) DEFAULT 0;

IF(pSpot<=97) -- condition 1
THEN

SELECT  @uid:=uid,
        nickname,
        lastsync,
        dob,
        gender,
        gender_preference,
        Latest_LAT,
        Latest_LON,
        country,
        imagetoken 
FROM search_optimized_table 
where country = @csid 
    and TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,DOB,CURDATE()) BETWEEN minAge and maxAge 
    and gender=@tempString 
    and lastsync BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -7 DAY)) 
    and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 0 DAY)) 
LIMIT con;

SET con = con - pSpot;
SET pSpot = pSpot + (Select found_rows());

WHILE x <= pSpot DO
    INSERT INTO temp_local_history (pUid) values (@uid);
END WHILE;
```

Comment: Is this the actual code used? I ask because it has an if condition which seems to be pointless (and is not terminated) and an infinite while loop.

Comment: @P.Salmon it's not the actual, just part of it.

Comment: If your select is doing what you want it to do then you might be able to drop the infinite while loop and substitute an insert select selecting only uid but using the same where conditions.

Comment: @P.Salmon there's a counter of 100 actually i set it. I'm finding something on cursors on google.

Comment: I don't see a counter of 100 in your code?

Comment: @P.Salmon It's quite long thou with 7 conditions . I've declared con = con - pSpot . The counter is the con.

Comment: I guess that there is an else if after the code segment you have published but there is still an infinite while loop in the segment because x will never be > pspot.

Comment: The `SELECT` statement is also assigning a value to your variable `@uid` (here, I'm assuming it is a single-valued element, like an integer). After the select, and regardless of the number of rows the select may return, this variable `@uid` holds **the last value fetch**. As a result, if you use it in the insert, it will always deploy the same value (as stated, the last fetched). Also, where is `x` getting its value from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i did a solution since the cursor method returns me 0 .

```
IF(pSpot<=97) -- condition 1
                THEN
                SET con = con - pSpot;
                INSERT INTO temp_local_search(
                SELECT @uid:=uid FROM search_optimized_table where country = @csid and TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,DOB,CURDATE()) BETWEEN minAge and maxAge and gender=@tempString and lastsync BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -7 DAY)) and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 0 DAY)) LIMIT con
                );
```